# Can I convert a root cellar into a small greenhouse?

Tags: vegetables, herbs, greenhouse

We barely use our root cellar at the moment and are in the midst of constructing garden beds and planters for vegetables, fruits, and herbs.

We don’t really have a great space indoor for growing plants, but we were thinking we might be able to convert unused root cellar space into a greenhouse since it naturally controls temperature and moisture, adding UV lights. The space would mainly be used to develop seedlings for planting after last frost or maintain a limited garden (like a few herbs, maybe a couple tomato plants).

We live in Ontario, Canada. Outside temperatures vary between -40C (dead of winter) and 45C (hottest summer). Not quite sure what the root cellar climate is like as we don’t yet have a thermometer or moisture meter.

Would there be a way to convert the root cellar space into a greenhouse? If so, how?

Can it still be used as a root cellar after conversion?

Comment: You can grow seedlings in a cupboard if you provide light and ventilation. You mention greenhouse a lot, which i picture as a structure where plenty of sun gets in heating the interior. Yes, you can grow plants in your root cellar, but get the word greenhouse out of your head.

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B. What term should I use instead of greenhouse? Would a root cellar be warm enough for proper plant growth and bearing fruit?